# Complete AsyncTask only when Firebase Task completes

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

How can I make an AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` only return when another async method completes?

On a high level, the Activity's purpose is to allow the user to upload a review. The review may also have images. Now in my code, I have two AsyncTasks: `ImageCompressionTask` and `ImageUploadTask`. Basically, once the user selects images to upload, `ImageCompressionTask` is executed for each image. In the `onPostExecute()` method of that task, `ImageUploadTask` is executed. The purpose of `ImageUploadTask` is to upload the compressed image and update the Firestore (database) with the download URL of the aforementioned uploaded image. Following is its code:

```
public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... bytes) {
        StorageReference ref = App.getFireStorage().getReference();
        ref = ref.child("review_images/" +
                mDestinationId + "/" +
                mExistingReview.getReviewId() + "/" +
                mUploadProgressCount);

        ref.putBytes(bytes[0]).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            mExistingReview.getImages().add(url);

            App.getFirestore().collection("reviews").document(mExistingReview.getReviewId()).set(mExistingReview);

            mUploadProgressCount++;
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that the `doInBackground()` returns prematurely. I understand WHY it happens (because the `ref.putBytes()` method runs asynchronously) but **I want it to wait until `ref.putBytes()` finishes.** How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at `CountDownLatch` at all? This might be useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Why are you even using an `AsyncTask`? No code you've written needs to run on a background thread (that's why `putBytes` requires you set a success listener).

Comment: @ninge I haven't used this before but looking at the docs, am I correcting in assuming that this is quite similar to the solution Gastón Saillén offered?

Comment: @ianhanniballake That is true, I was hesitant about putting network code in `ImageCompressionTask`'s main thread hence why I did it this way. Redundancy aside, are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: @NajmSheikh it should be a simpler solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem with `ObservableInteger`

is a listener that listen for values

```
private ObservableInteger mObsInt;

 //Listener
        mObsInt = new ObservableInteger();
        mObsInt.set(0);

        mObsInt.setOnIntegerChangeListener(new OnIntegerChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onIntegerChanged(int newValue)
            {
                if (mObsInt.get()==1)
                    Log.e("Downloads"," mObsInt 1");
                Log.e("Download1"," Finished first process ");
                if (mObsInt.get()==2){
                    Log.e("Downloads"," mObsInt 2");
                    Log.e("Download2"," Finished second process ");
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(LoginActivity.this, Principal.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

and then just do this (after a process has finished or an asynctask)

```
mObsInt.set(mObsInt.get()+1);
```

so it will count, if the first thing finish obsInt will be 1 , and when the second one finish, obsInt will be 2, so after obsInt == 2 , you can move on to the other activity or process you need

happy coding !

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I understand this correctly, you're basically incrementing the observable int every step of the way. Once it reaches a certain count, you finish whatever it is you need to do. If so, what if some error happens and the counter never reaches the "success" value? How are you handling that?

Comment: Also, are you using a different library for the `ObservableInteger`? Different than the `android.databinding` package?

Comment: ObservableInteger comes with AndroidStudio https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableInt.html

Comment: you can handle however you want if it never reachs one of the counters, since i need to reach every async in my app, i just fires again the async if there is no process, or give the user a UI saying "try again later"

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check it this way :

```
 @Override
protected synchronized Void doInBackground(byte[]... bytes) {
    StorageReference ref = App.getFireStorage().getReference();
    ref = ref.child("review_images/" +
            mDestinationId + "/" +
            mExistingReview.getReviewId() + "/" +
            mUploadProgressCount);

    ref.putBytes(bytes[0]).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
        String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
        mExistingReview.getImages().add(url);

        App.getFirestore().collection("reviews").document(mExistingReview.getReviewId()).set(mExistingReview);

        mUploadProgressCount++;
    });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Otherwise your portion code which is ref.putBytes() keep in synchronized block like below : 

synchronized(this){
//keep your code here with return if required
}

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

```
 public class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Integer, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... bytes) {

                // Initialize CountDownLatch
                final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

                StorageReference ref = App.getFireStorage().getReference();
                ref = ref.child("review_images/" +
                        mDestinationId + "/" +
                        mExistingReview.getReviewId() + "/" +
                        mUploadProgressCount);

                ref.putBytes(bytes[0]).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    mExistingReview.getImages().add(url);

                    App.getFirestore().collection("reviews").document(mExistingReview.getReviewId()).set(mExistingReview);

                    mUploadProgressCount++;

                   // Start count down
                   signal.countDown();
                });

                // Wait for putBytes to return and handle case if
                // threads get interrupted.
                // You can also specify a maximum time to wait before 
                // displaying error to user (ie Try Again)
                try {
                    signal.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
```